# Mongoid Query for the content on Array inside a Document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm Trying to retrieve if some info exist for create connections between users with Mongoid and Rails, here is the code:

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController
  def addNew
    @newFriend = params[:username]
    puts "***value of @newFriend***"
    puts @newFriend
    puts "***end****"
    Contact.where(owner: current_user).where(friendlist: params[:username]) do |contact|
      puts "***value of @contactAlreadyExists***"
      puts contact
      puts "***end****"
      if contact == nil
        Contact.find_or_create_by(owner: current_user) do |contact|
          contact.push(friendlist: params[:username])
        end
      end
    end
    redirect_to "/"
  end
end
```

The console don't show anything from

```
puts "***value of @contactAlreadyExists***"
      puts contact
      puts "***end****"
```

Comment: Don't you mean `Contact.where(...).each do`?

Comment: now the collection is empty, must create if not exists.

Comment: But are you expecting `Contact.where(...) do |contact|` to do? You're handing a block to `where`, not to an iterator over the query's result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a temporal solution cause before add someone not able to going inside the query again on the line

```
user.contacts.find_or_create_by(owner: user.id) do |contact|
```

**The code:**

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController
      def addNew
        @newFriend = params[:username]
        puts "***value of @newFriend***"
        puts @newFriend
        puts "***end****"
        User.find_by(username: current_user.username) do |user|
          puts "*** here enters***"
          user.contacts.find_or_create_by(owner: user.id) do |contact|
            User.find_by(username: params[:username]) do |friend|
              puts "***enter on friend"
              puts friend
              contact.push(friendlist: friend.id)
            end
            puts "***contact***"
            puts contact
            puts "***end****"
          end
        end
        redirect_to "/"
      end
    end
```